# Tomcat urlrewritefilter - from directory path to root path?

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

My Tomcat web app has this path:

```
http://192.168.0.1/app/
```

How to create a alias for it like this (don't want to type the `app`)?

```
http://192.168.0.1/
```

I'm not allowed to change the `server-mapping` in `web.xml`.

I tried the **Tuckey URLRewrite**

```
<rule>
    <from>/</from>
    <to type="redirect">/app/</to>
</rule>
```

But when try to access the `http://192.168.0.1/`, it makes the URL becomes this and doesn't work.

```
 http://192.168.0.1/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

`<rule>
    <from>^/*</from>
    <to type="redirect">/app/</to>
 </rule>`